# check if a buttons has a set image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, if-statement

I am trying to have a button that checks if it has an icon if so do X other wise do Y

```
        if button.currentImage!.isEqual(UIImage(named: "check")) {
            print("X")
        } else {
            print("Y")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `currentImage` could be `nil`  then you need to safely use `?` instead of `!`

```
    if button.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "check")) ?? false {
        print("X")
    } else {
        print("Y")
    }
```

if it's only check if image  exists then no compare

```
    if button.currentImage != nil {
        print("X")
    } else {
        print("Y")
    }
```